# If I use string.contains() on a string that may have regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

If I use string.contains() on a string that may have regular expressions, will the regular expressions trigger? For example string.contains("alpha\wbet").

Am I right in thinking that contains will be fine but matches will not?
Thank you

Comment: You could.. you know.. try it..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`String.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) accepts `CharSequence` as argument and doesn't "trigger" regexes that it or processing string may contain.

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the **specified sequence of char values**.

From [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 0):

Contains take a string as parameter and looks for that string. It doesn't work as regexp. If you want to search for regular experssion use string.matches

Answer (score 0):

It accepts char sequence as a paramater. If you give regex contains method consider that as char sequence. Below provide sample program depict the behavior.

```
 String inp="12345";
 System.out.println(inp.contains("34"));
 System.out.println(inp.contains("[34]"));
 Matcher m=Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(inp);
 System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Output:

```
 true
 false
 true
```

The output of the testcase shows how it contains method works for regex.